# PHP FPM crashes server

Tags: apache2, php, php-fpm

I have a LAMP stack on a droplet with all the latest specs.

My PHP FPM settings:

```
pm.max_children = 45
pm.start_servers = 15
pm.min_spare_servers = 15
pm.max_spare_servers = 20
```

I have 4GB memory and 80GB droplet.

I get this warning in php log:

```
WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children; there are 12 idle, and 24 total children
```

First, my websites run super fast until I get a white screen.

I have tried different settings but I can't seem to hit the right numbers.

Comment: How much memory does each HTTP request consume? 15 servers x 45 children = 675 threads. That works out to about 5MB of dedicated memory each (many PHP-based sites rely heavily on shared memory, which allows a PHP process to "consume more"). If you're running something like Moodle or Joomla, the available memory will be exhausted rather quickly, then the server will spend a remarkable amount of time swapping to disk ... or killing processes in an effort to recover resources 

Comment: Hi, about 200MB. I just made PHP FPM restart automatically on failure and changed my settings to 45, 17, 17, 20. Thanks!